# How to exclude self-traffic in google code from google analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics, google-code

I'm currently using Google Analytics to get reports for my project hosted on code.google.com.

I'd like to exclude the traffic generated by myself. I know that Google Analytics basically offers two way to filter my traffic: by IP address and by cookies.
The ISP gives me a dynamic IP address so I can't filter by IP address. I should then use the cookies method.

I read I should add some javascript code to my site to set the cookie.
My question is: how can I add into the wiki pages of google code the javascript I need? Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://ode2code.blogspot.se/2009/02/how-to-exclude-self-traffic-from-google.html contains a solution that seems valid:

> **Setting the cookie:**
>
> Create a new page on your domain, containing the following code:
>
> body onLoad="javascript:__utmSetVar('no_report')"
>
> Visit this page from all computers that you would like to exclude from
>   your reports, to set the cookie on each machine.
>
> **Creating the filter:**
>
> You'll need to create an Exclude filter to remove data from visitors
>   with this cookie.
>
> - Filter Type: Custom filter > Exclude
> - Filter Field: User Defined
> - Filter Pattern: no_report
> - Case Sensitive: No
>
> **How to create a filter?**
>
> http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55494

Use this together with this wiki article http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WorkingWithGoogleGadgets to create a gadget containing the script that you may include on your page.

Comment: I know this procedure, the problem is: on google code they give you only wiki pages, and it seems you cannot add javascript code inside it. My question was: how can I add the javascript I need?

Comment: Why at all send events? We can do this using cookies. My attempt here: http://ankitjain.info/ankit/2013/11/09/exclude-self-referral-ip-address-google-analytics-disable/

Answer (score 2):

Several chrome and firefox extensions are available that allow you to block google analytics tracking on a per-site basis.  I have found this is the easiest way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Google Analytics Opt-out Browser Add-on](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout), though it will disable tracking on all sites altogether.

Answer (score -1):

how about using the campaign tracking feature to create a specific urm URL you send out to any person you wish to exclude  from reports?
Then add a campaign filter, how's that?

not sure how long the campaign cookie will be stored, may need everyone to click that camapaign URL every few weeks?