# Universal Analytics (analytics.js) Ignoring own traffic

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

From google's documentation:

> The analytics.js snippet is part of Universal Analytics, which is
>   currently in public beta. New users should use analytics.js. Existing
>   ga.js users should create a new web property for analytics.js and dual
>   tag their site. It is perfectly safe to include both ga.js and
>   analytics.js snippets on the same page.

However, I can't seem to find a way to set up a filter to exclude my own traffic with a cookie. There is [this for ga.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826062/how-to-exclude-self-traffic-in-google-code-from-google-analytics-reports), but as far as I can tell there is no way to set a custom variable with analytics.js, and I get get a custom dimension to work.

Edit: What I've done thus far:

1. [Set up a custom dimension called 'ignore' in GA via the UI](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en)
2. [Created a filter specifying the custom dimension from step 1](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?rd=1)
3. called `ga('set', 'dimension1', 1);` my website

traffic is not ignored

Comment: This question seems off-topic unless you have some specific problem with code you've written; in which case your question is lacking that code.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO the question is 'how to programmatically  set a custom variable and have it recognized by a filter in ga'. How is that even remotely off-topic?

Comment: "Real Time has always been great for rapid testing and debugging of your tracking code and now with profile support you can do the same when creating profile filters. When you change the filters in your profile, you should see the effects in the real time reports within a couple of hours. We are working to make this even quicker going forward." From: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/10/real-time-analytics-supports-profiles.html, I'll give an update in a few hours, and summarize my findings

Comment: well it's been 4 hours, and it still doesn't appear to work. I'll try again in the morning, but it doesn't appear if latency to propagate to real time is the issue.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. Existing solutions only apply to the old ga.js stuff and don't work in Universal Analytics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just set your own cookie and check against it using the [opt out var](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout)?

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXX-Y'] = true;
```

Comment: it just bothers me that I can't get a custom dimension to work. It definitely should work. I'll accept this and put my solution as a separate answer. hopefully someone will be able to improve it, or figure out where I am going wrong

Comment: Well, `ga('set', 'ignore', '1');` isn't going to send in as a custom metric. You'd need to do `ga('set', 'metric1', 1);` instead. You won't use the friendly name of the variable in the code, just metric[1-20] or dimension[1-20].

Comment: Great point @MisterPhilip, I'll correct my code and see if that works. If it does. Do you want to summarize that as another answer, and I'll accept that one...?

Comment: just took a look at my code, and unfortunately the error was with my post on stack overflow, not my code. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This should work, but for some reason it does not. I was hoping someone could improve on this**

1. [Set up a custom dimension called 'ignore' in GA via the UI](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en)
2. [Created a filter specifying the custom dimension from step 1](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?rd=1)
3. call `ga('set', 'dimension1', '1');` before `ga('send', 'pageview');`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [Google Analytics Opt-out Browser Add-on](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout). It will disable tracking for all sites though.